# Keep an image in the centered when resized

Tags: html, css

How could I keep the image centered without making it squished just like what https://stockx.com/ has done with the image disappearing from both sides instead of just the right side

```
*{
  margin: 0%;
}
header{
  width: auto;
  height: 55vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/2300x612");
}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/tiles.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style/main.css">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <div class="contentBar">
      <img src="./content/svg/stocx.svg" />
      <ul>
        <img src="./content/svg/search.svg" alt="search">
        <img src="./content/svg/account.svg" alt="account">
        <img src="./content/svg/help.svg" alt="help">
        <img src="./content/svg/notifications.svg" alt="notifications">
      </ul>
    </div>
    <input class="searchBar" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
  </header>


</body>
</html>
```

[image: shows the image not centered]

[image: shows the image centered as it is fully stretched out]

Comment: To which of the 6 images in your example do you refer?  Can you cut down the example code enough to just be the one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add: `background-size: cover;` if the image has wide aspect-ratio or `background-size: contain;` for the opposite ratio

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size

```css
div{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;           /* <-- use this */
  background-position: center;      /* <-- use this */
  background-image: url("https://via.placeholder.com/1350x1000");
  
  outline: 2px solid red;
  height: 200px;
  resize: both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: unfortunately Cover does the same thing (disappears from the right), and contain shrinks the height instead of width

Comment: look at my updated answer which has code example. you can even resize the div and see how well centered the background image is

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't know about "background-position: center;"!

Answer (score 0):

```
header{
  width: auto;
  height: 55vh;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-image: url("http://placehold.it/2300x612");
}
```